# JTextPane autoscroll works only one time

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane, autoscroll

I have two JTextPane and set all them to autoscroll vertically, but for some reason that I don't undertstand only one is working.

What could be the reason?

```
    JTextPane textA = new JTextPane();
    textA.setName(text);
    textA.setContentType("text/html");
    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textA.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
    JScrollPane filler = new JScrollPane (textA, 
    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    JTextPane textB = new JTextPane();
    textB.setName(text + "_T");
    textB.setFont(textA.getFont());
    DefaultCaret caret_T = (DefaultCaret)textB.getCaret();
    caret_T.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
    JScrollPane filler_T = new JScrollPane (textB, 
    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    panel.add(filler); panel.add(filler_T);
```

filler_T (textB) is the only one that is working

Answer (score 1):

You have not used any layout for your `panel`. So `JScrollPane filler_T` is placed over `JScrollPane filler` , so `JTextPane textA` is not visible.

Use a layout, for example add this lines in your code:

```
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
panel.add(filler,BorderLayout.NORTH); 
panel.add(filler_T,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Your window will look like:

[image]

Full running code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

public class TestScroll extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestScroll frame = new TestScroll();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public TestScroll() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(panel);



        JTextPane textA = new JTextPane();
        textA.setName("text");
        textA.setContentType("text/html");
        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textA.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
        JScrollPane filler = new JScrollPane (textA, 
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        JTextPane textB = new JTextPane();
        textB.setName("text" + "_T");
        textB.setFont(textA.getFont());
        DefaultCaret caret_T = (DefaultCaret)textB.getCaret();
        caret_T.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
        JScrollPane filler_T = new JScrollPane (textB, 
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        panel.add(filler,BorderLayout.NORTH); 
        panel.add(filler_T,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();

    }

}
```

Also for better understanding read [LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)